# Represent a City in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

Say, I build a dynamic map in WPF.

I need to represent in this map locations(say, cities).

The representation of a city is simple: a dot (circle or image) and the text.

Both text and dot image are customizable.

What would you recommend using as a CityControl in WPF?
[image]
Examples:

- A **UserControl** having an `<Ellipse>`(or *picture*) and `<TextBlock>`?
- A **CustomControl** extending a `<TextBlock>` with a specific style? (is it possible to set the style inside this control)
- ...something else?

Comment: Why not just have it as a positioned image??

Answer (score 1):

Google something like "WPF UserControl vs CustomControl" and you'll get a whole list of articles pointing out the differences.

[This one](http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html) has a fairly simple explanation of the differences. You'll need to choose which one is best for your situation.

Comment: Thanks, even if I didn't ask about the difference between UC and CC.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an `Ellipse`, you can then define different properties such as color etc.

```
<CityControl>
   <Ellipse>
   <GeoInformation>
   <TextBlock>
   etc..
```

Comment: so, what is it? a WPF UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `UserControl`.
It'd contain a `Canvas`.
Inside the `Canvas`, put a `TextBlock` and a centered `Ellipse`.
Add needed properties. First one can be degrees for text to position respect to ellipse center.

But that's just 1 idea. The possibilities are endless.